# Deploy .NET 4 Full to XP via GPO or WSUS

Tags: group-policy, wsus, .net-4.0

I am trying to deploy the full version of .NET 4.0 to client workstations running Windows XP.

I have tried creating an MSI from the .exe using various free tools and assigning the install through a GPO, but this has not been successful. My MSI's will work when I run them manually, but not through GPO.  I have tried applying this to both user and computer.

I have looked at WSUS, however the only relevant feature packs for XP are for the client version and we require the full version.  Full versions of .NET 4 on WSUS are only available for servers.

Is anyone aware of a solution? Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any kind of failure messages?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your event logs after trying to run the GPO with the MSI associated.  It'll tell you what went wrong.
[here's a page that will help you interpret any errors you find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look at:

1. GPO application installs require administrator privileges. By definition, User GPOs run in the user's context. So, if you're trying to install using a User Policy, the user must be an administrator.  Since most users are not administrators, this leaves you with running the install as a Computer policy.
2. Computer GPO application installations run with the machine context, so it should have sufficient permissions to complete the install. However, Computer GPO application installs only fire during computer start, so a reboot will be necessary.
3. The MSI must be silent. If the installer requires ANY user interaction or displays ANY type of GUI, it will fail silently.